# C programming: array

Tags: c

The following C code does not give a fully correct answer.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,a[3][3];
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=i+j;
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

When run, it gives erroneous outcome for (2,3)th element. What is the fault here?

Comment: Array index start with `0` in c and c++.

Comment: Any book would clearly state this.

Comment: The comments about arrays starting at 0 are spot on here. One other thing, you probably want to remove `#include<conio.h>` as you currently aren't using it.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are zero-origin in C.

Change

```
(i=1;i<=3;i++)
```

to

```
(i=0;i<3;i++)
```

(And same for the `j` loop).

Comment: As well `(j=1;j<=3;j++)` to `(j=0;j<=3;j++)`

Comment: Cool .. BTW the comment was not meant to you but rather to OP. So he don't misses the other part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array defined as for example

```
int a[N];
```

then the valid range of indices is `[0, N - 1]`

In C/C++ indices start from 0.

Your program in C could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const int N = 3;
    int a[N][N];

    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\n" );
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = i + j + 2;
            printf( "%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need to include header `<conio.h>` because neither its declaration is used.